# android-connect to a specific pc over wifi

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, wifi

I have a TCP server in my PC and a client in my android phone. I want that the phone will connect to the computer every time they both are on the same network.
How do I scan all the connected devices to the same wifi network of the phone and choose the specific PC every time? (I noticed that my PC's IP is changing so I can't use the address as a constant)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have written the PC app and can make updates to it, then you can add a UDP socket to it that listens on the same NIC(s) as the TCP socket.  The Android client can then send a UDP packet to the PC's UDP port using the WiFi network's subnet broadcast IP.  The packet will be sent to the same port on every device connected to the subnet.  If the PC app receives the packet, it can send a reply directly to the sender's IP.  If the Android client receives the reply, it will thus know the PC's IP and can connect to its TCP socket.

To get the WiFi's subnet broadcast IP, you can do this:

[Android Broadcast Address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781359/65863)

```
private InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow

    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      quads[k] = (byte) (broadcast >> (k * 8));
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

On the other hand, if you have not written the PC app and/or cannot update it, then you will have to either:

- make a separate app to run alongside the TCP app to handle the UDP packets.
- if all else fails, have the Android client simply loop through every possible IP address on the subnet (you can easily calculate the starting and ending IP addresses based on the `ipAddress` and `netmask` values reported by `DhcpInfo`), trying to connect to the TCP port on each IP until one finally succeeds.  This approach is slow, especially if the subnet has a lot of available IPs, but it would work.